# Is handling unicode character with wchar_t good? Does it not cause any problems?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf

I have been searching for a way to handle Polish words. I read about utf8, 16, 32, but any conversion from `char` to `utf` gives me different letter.

wchar_t gives a correct letter, though.

Is it ok to do it that way?

What about performance if for example I will use only ascii, just because? Does it impact an application any way?

Comment: multi-character encodings are a matter of interpretation. a `std::string` can hold a utf-8 string. `wchar_t` is only 16-bit and thus not sufficient to hold all unicode code points (would need 32-bit). It just has a higher range than `char` without resorting to more than one element to encode it

Comment: How do you define "works" from "does not work"? Within which context and with which compilers and in what code does it "work" or "not work"?

Comment: @CruzJean Who says `wchar_t` is 16 bits?

Comment: @melpomene https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: @CruzJean "*32 bits on systems that support Unicode.*"

Comment: @melpomene It may not be.

Comment: For Polish alone proper 8-bit encoding (ISO 8859-2? Not sure if there are other more popular) should be sufficient.

Comment: `wchar_t` is 16-bit on Windows.

Comment: @n0rd Not every computer runs Windows.

Comment: Sure but saying "wchar_t is 32 bits on systems that support Unicode" is wrong.

Comment: @n0rd It literally says _"A notable exception is Windows, where wchar_t is 16 bits and holds UTF-16 code units"_ right after it

Comment: The comment above absolutely does not say that.

Comment: @n0rd The conversation you jumped into was about the page Cruz Jean linked to, which absolutely does say that. Notice how melpomene used quotation marks to indicate that.

Comment: You're right "does not work" and "work" might confuse a bit. Let me edit it a bit.

Comment: Not everyone will go and read the full article. The quote above is specifically "carved" to omit the part that supports the 16-bit `wchar_t` claim that is being contested. Objecting to a "`wchar_t` is 16 bit" claim with a "`wchar_t` is 32-bit on systems that support Unicode" does not help anyone unfamiliar with the subject to understand the mess we are in.

Comment: @n0rd The thread was a rebuttal of "`wchar_t` is [always] 16 bits" and it perfectly served that purpose. We don't need to reproduce the entire article's contents here, nor should we be expected to. The quote wasn't in an answer, it was in a discussion between two people (neither of whom was you). It was also largely true - Windows does not "support Unicode" in the proper sense: it cannot, because it does not have a character type large enough (well, until C++11's `char32_t` anyway!). Can we put this to an end now?

Comment: UTF-16 is as multi-byte encoding as UTF-8 is and both can represent full range of Unicode. What absence of Unicode support you are talking about?

Comment: And I'm sorry, but do you deny me a right to jump on a conversation on a public web site?

Comment: @n0rd No, but your argument seemed to be _"Not everyone will go and read the full article"_. The quote wasn't for "everyone". It was for one specific person, who already had all the context necessary to understand it without confusion. You're just making trouble.

Comment: Also see: http://site.icu-project.org/design/cpp The value of picking libicu is not in the data type, but in the Unicode compliant algorithms shipping with it. I'm not a C++ expert, but I'm under the impression `wchar_t` does not help you much in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two different things:

1. **Storage**

   How you store the bytes that make up your text string. Will that be in an array of `char` (single-byte) values? Or will it be in the form of `wchar_t` (multi-byte) values?
2. **Encoding**

   Your computer (and you!) needs to know what to do with the values in those bytes. What do they mean? Regardless of storage, they could be ASCII, some [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page), UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, Klingon, anything.

*Usually*, for historical reasons, we pick `char` for single-byte encodings (e.g. ASCII) and UTF-8, and `wchar_t` for UTF-16 (particularly on Windows, which has 16-bit `wchar_t`s and generally assumes this combination throughout its API — note that it inaccurately calls this simply "Unicode").

Performance doesn't really come into it, though you'll save time and energy converting between different encodings if you pick *one* and stick to it (and use a storage mechanism that fits the string libraries you're using). Sometimes your OS will help determine that choice, but we can't tell you what it will be.

Similarly, your statements about what "works" and "doesn't work" are very vague, and likely false.

We can't say what's "ok" without knowing the requirements of your project, and what sort of computer it'll run on, and with what technologies. I will, though, make a tremendous generalisation: in the olden days, you might have used [Mazovia encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazovia_encoding), an altered codepage that included Polish characters; nowadays, you probably want to make portability and interchange as easy as possible (because why not?!), so you'd be encouraged to stick with UTF-16 over `wchar_t` on Windows, and UTF-8 over `char` otherwise.

*(From C++20 we'll also have `char8_t`, a storage mechanism specifically designed to signify that it stores UTF-8-encoded data; however, it's going to be some time before you see this in widespread use, if at all. You can read more about C++'s character types on [cppreference.com's article about "Fundamental types"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types))*

Comment: ASCII encoding is barely used anywhere. ASCII is 7-bit. Forget about it. What actually is used depends on the system and selected locale.

Comment: @n0rd That's true; I was just expanding the answer to talk about codepages a little but I don't want to go into too much detail on this question.

Comment: but, I heard that utf-8 can represent 4 bytes, so it is 32 bits (actually we can use 21 
 bits), so it is more than UTF-16 and as discussed above or the same on different OS than windows. My point is, why even use utf-16/32 over 8?

Comment: @BrodaJarek3 because of History.  This blog post includes a little bit of what happened on MS-Windows:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190830-00/?p=102823

Comment: @BrodaJarek3 It's up to 32 bits, spread over as many bytes as it takes to hold that information. As for "why even use utf-16/32 over 8" well that is a very good question and most people will tell you "don't" :) http://utf8everywhere.org/ EXCEPT because Windows API uses UTF-16 throughout, if you used UTF-8 you'd be constantly converting back and forth, so they've kind of made the decision for you there.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Now I know all I what I wanted to know.